# How to search a string in an array using grep?

Tags: perl, grep

I have an array which contains some file names. I'm trying to grep the particular file name which matches the string.

```
@arr=qw(INS.INPUT01.S7779902 INS.INPUT01.S7779903 INS.INPUT01.S7779904);
$str = "7779902";

if (grep{$_=~ /$str/} @arr){
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: What would you like to do if there was more than one match?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know which elements matched, you need to do something with the return value of `grep`:

```
my @matched = grep { /$str/ } @arr;
for my $x (@matched) {
    print $x, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You presumably want the file name in the list that matches?

That looks like this

```
my ($match) = grep /\Q$str/, @arr

print $match, "\n" if defined $match
```

This will show the *first* matching name. Any others will be ignored